# How to set separate media queries to effect the same element?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, element

I am trying to optimize my mobile webpage experience throughout several iPhone screens, particularly the 5/5s and 6/6s. I'm trying to effect the position attribute of an element in a different way depending on the screen i.e, "if the screen is a 5/5s, do this", "if the screen is a 6/6s, do this". However, one query just overrides the other instead of doing its own specific thing.

Here is my CSS:

```
/* for iPhone 6/6S  */
@media (max-width:730px) {
  .fore-man {
    top: 1100px;
}
/*  for iPhone 5/5S */
@media (max-width:560px) {
  .fore-man {
    top: 1100px;
}
```

How do I correct it to be screen specific & not just override the previous query?

Answer (score 0):

Would adding a min width to your 6/6s query do the trick?

```
/* for iPhone 6/6S  */
@media (max-width:730px) and (min-width: 561px) {
    .fore-man {
      top: 1100px;
    }
}
/*  for iPhone 5/5S */
@media (max-width:560px) {
    .fore-man {
      top: 1100px;
    }
}
```

According to this article, targeting device screens is better done with device-width properties.

Take a look, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```
/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the element inspector? Are the rules being applied and overridden, or never being applied at all?

Comment: aha! I also just noticed in your code example, your missing closing curly brackets on your media queries. I've edited my answer to reflect...